# Pycharm Run Linux Command before Console

Tags: python, pycharm, ipython

Hi I am currently using pycharm to work on a python project. I am mostly running the code on a remote server which I have easy ssh access to. I currently have pycharm setup that I can easily upload/download files and use the ipython console with my environment. However, to fully be able to use the resources of the server I need to be able to run a linux command before running my python files or calling ipython so that I can have the resources I need to debug and whatnot. Is there a way to tell pycharm to run a specific command before starting my remote environment for the ipython console. (i.e instead of it doing `conda activate environment; ipython` it would do `linux command; conda activate environment; ipython`?

Thank you